# JavaScript code to search a website for a given string?

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a project using Node.JS, and I am trying to create a function that can search websites for certain strings. For instance, if I called

```
myFunction("Street Address", "www.insertLinkHere.com")
```

then the function would search the given link for any instance of "Street Address." If the given string is here, it returns the phrase it is in, and if it is not, it simply returns a message saying the string could not be located.

Is there any pre-existing JavaScript function I can import that does something similar to this, or perhaps something I could use to at least do the initial search of the string?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Unfortunately, there are a few [rules and guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) that cover [what kind of questions SO is for](/help/on-topic), with the main criterium being "do you have code that does not work, despite being sure it should, and your own debugging/research efforts are not helping you solve the problem?". Unfortunately, as a general "how do I start using language X", this question is off-topic for SO.

Comment: `var strExists = new RegExp("Street Address").test(myWebsiteString);`

Comment: A very interesting question, nevertheless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an [Extracty](https://extracty.com) endpoint for you that does this. It goes through all p and span elements and returns the text of the elements, which contain the string. You can call it here:

https://api.extracty.com/v1/334/610f5674-51ac-407f-b3af-65697b8f00be/?search=origin&url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin

As you can see, the url and the search string are parameter. This is the code I used on Extracty:

```
return $('span:contains(' + extracty.args.search + '), p:contains(' + extracty.args.search + ')').get().map(function(element) {
  return element.textContent.trim()
})
```

You can fork the endpoint here: https://app.extracty.com/endpoint?id=334

Answer (score 0):

Try out one of many existing nodejs web crawling libraries or tutorials.

Google search suggests the following:

1. https://scotch.io/tutorials/scraping-the-web-with-node-js
2. https://github.com/sylvinus/node-crawler
3. http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-make-a-simple-web-crawler-in-javascript-and-node-js/
4. https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-crawler

And there is many more to be found at www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create search functionality with JavaScript but you need to specify what you are searching in. Is it a sql database? Is it xml files? This tutorial would be a good start if you know nothing about making server requests using JavaScript. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp